# Replit Discord Unbound Local Errors for no reason

Tags: python, discord, bots, replit

I have made a discord bot using Replit and all of a sudden I get an UnboundLocalError. It has only just started doing it after working many times previously without changing anything. Here is my code:

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

This as mentioned should work like a charm; however, I start getting this random error which I can't seem to fix:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 553, in on_message
    if message.author == client.user:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'client' referenced before assignment
```

This is really annoying me as it was just working perfectly and now it's not. I'm using Replit and have tried everything to resolve it.

Comment: is there any other code in `on_message`?

Comment: Nope. Seems to be a bug with Replit? Haven't added any code or deleted any and it's doing this randomly.